# Override comma separator for query string array in URL

Tags: java, url

I have a query string like this

**&category=category,id&category=promotion**

the string "**category,id**" is one string but it recognize it as an array
then it query it as two words
how to make it just a single string...

Comment: *"it recognize it as an array"* What is *"it"*?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen
There three ways to send an array in url request

First is separated by commas
**name=Actor1,Actor2,Actor3&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505**
Second 
**name=Actor1&name=Actor2&name=Actor3&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505**
Third
name[0]=Actor1&name[1]=Actor2&name[2]=Actor3&startDate=20120101&endDate=20120505

what i use is number two but if i pass a string like what i described
it recognize it as an array

Comment: Have you tried replacing the comma with `%2C`?

Comment: I think you are trying to send  value and ID seperated by ,   try category_id  instead   .   By the way name=Actor1,Actor2,Actor  is a format of an Array ... so its working as expected .  DOnt use , to seperate values in URL

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen
I already try that but same result

Comment: Have you tried `%5C%2C`?

Comment: @AshishKumar
You saying that i must avoid , in my string?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen
same result, still it recognize the comma as an array 
then return it as two string..

Comment: How did your server receive it?

Comment: @Frank.D

I'm using **javax.portlet.PortletRequest**

I'm using **getParameterValues()** method

to get the query string

then assign it to a String[] variable

Comment: did u try with urlencoding?

Comment: @sajib

already do that 
but it gives me two string not one string
what i want is to return this 
"category,id"

not 
"category"
"id"